# Module not found Error: You attempted to import which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, audio-player

I am currently making a music player app on React, and am new to React js. Not sure why i'm getting this error, having been following the exact steps on the tutorial I'm watching.

The full Error Code is:

```
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../components/Player which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

For better clarity, This is the code for the Player component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PlayerDetails from './PlayerDetails';

function Player(props) {
    return (  
        <div className="c-player">
            <audio></audio>
            <h4>Now playing</h4>
            <PlayerDetails song={props.song}/>
            {/*CONTROLS */}
            <p><strong> Next Up:</strong> {props.nextSong.title} {props.nextSong.artist}</p>

        </div>
    );
}

export default Player;
```

And this is the Code on App.js:

```
 import { useState } from "react";
 import Player from "../components/Player";

function App() {
const [songs, setSongs]= useState([
{
  title: "1",
  artist: "1",
  img_src: "./images/song-1.jpg/",
  src: "./music/song-1.mp3"
},
{
  title: "2",
  artist: "2",
  img_src: "./images/song-2.jpg/",
  src: "./music/song-2.mp3"
},
{
  title: "3",
  artist: "3",
  img_src: "./images/song-3.jpg/",
  src: "./music/song-3.mp3"
},
{
  title: "4",
  artist: "4",
  img_src: "./images/song-4.jpg/",
  src: "./music/song-4.mp3"
}

]);
const [currentSongIndex, setCurrentSongIndex]= useState(0);
const [nextSongIndex, setnextSongIndex]= useState (currentSongIndex + 1);


  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Player 
     songs= {songs[currentSongIndex]}
     nextSong={songs[nextSongIndex]}
     />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the folder structure:

[image]
Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2):

I think path for your Player component is incorrect

```
import Player from "../components/Player";
```

Try this:

```
import Player from "./components/Player";
```

Comment: Hey Jineesh, Unfortunately that didn't resolve the issue. It's still giving the same error message.

Comment: is the Player component is outside the src folder?

Comment: could you share me the folder structure?

Comment: In the tutorial, the component folder is outside of the src folder. I saw this error when i followed the tutorial step-by-step. So instead, components folder inside my src folder and didn't experience the error anymore. However, now I my screen is blank for some reason, and I cannot see any of my components. I just uploaded a picture of my src folder structure above:

Comment: Now change import path to `import Player from "./components/Player";`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

Your components folder should be under the src folder, then set the path carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Change your path to

```js
import Player from "./../components/Player"
```

Comment: Although this answer is not correct, please always specify why you think this potential solution will work based on the post. At the very least it will incite a discussion that might lead to the correct answer. In addition, if you are not sure of a solution always use comments on the post rather than an answer.